# Error importing json file in Lex Chatbot AWS

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

[image]I am trying to build a chatbot with Lex to get the instance details. I am trying to build the Bot with json..  When I import json file it says "The JSON structure in the request isn't valid. Check the JSON structure and try your request again.".. Tried with several codes and same issue. 
I dont think the problem is with the code, but am I missing something.. 
Or please guide me to create a Bot with Json file.

Thanks

```
{
"name": "AWSBot",
"intents": [
    {
        "intentName": "RunningInstances",
        "intentVersion": "7"
    },
    {
        "intentName": "InstanceStatus",
        "intentVersion": "2"
    },
    {
        "intentName": "GetAddress",
        "intentVersion": "2"
    },
    {
        "intentName": "ShutdownReason",
        "intentVersion": "9"
    },
    {
        "intentName": "Discovery",
        "intentVersion": "1"
    },
    {
        "intentName": "StartInstance",
        "intentVersion": "3"
    },
    {
        "intentName": "GetLaunchTime",
        "intentVersion": "1"
    },
    {
        "intentName": "StopInstance",
        "intentVersion": "3"
    }
],
"clarificationPrompt": {
    "messages": [
        {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "Sorry, can you please repeat that?"
        }
    ],
    "maxAttempts": 5
},
"abortStatement": {
    "messages": [
        {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "Sorry, I could not understand. Goodbye."
        }
    ]
},
"status": "READY",
"lastUpdatedDate": 1508081752.212,
"createdDate": 1495671152.723,
"idleSessionTTLInSeconds": 300,
"voiceId": "0",
"checksum": "4a7de68b-468c-43d0-8c6d-1e37e3f99ed3",
"version": "$LATEST",
"locale": "en-US",
"childDirected": false
}

{
    "name": "RunningInstances",
    "slots": [],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "What's the number of running instances",
        "Tell me how many instances are running.",
        "How many servers are up"
    ],
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1498612715.974,
    "createdDate": 1495671367.924,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "bd5811f5-9ae1-4381-8f4a-c9dda7f690c8"
}


{
    "name": "InstanceStatus",
    "slots": [],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "Tell me the status of my instances.",
        "Status report.",
        "how are my instances"
    ],
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1498612653.385,
    "createdDate": 1496013449.711,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "1525e15a-aa06-49c1-8031-68c14c861376"
}


{
    "name": "GetAddress",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "instance_id",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "instance_id",
            "slotTypeVersion": "2",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which instance?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 1,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        },
        {
            "name": "short_code",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which instance?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 2,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        }
    ],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "What is the IP address of instance {instance_id}",
        "What is the IP address of instance {short_code}",
        "what's the name of {instance_id}",
        "what's the name of {short_code}",
        "hostname {instance_id}",
        "hostname {short_code}"
    ],
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1508081701.779,
    "createdDate": 1499550333.168,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "5ae31dcd-fde0-4cb4-b57e-7cb0ed7de635"
}


{
    "name": "ShutdownReason",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "instance_id",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "instance_id",
            "slotTypeVersion": "2",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which instance?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 1,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        },
        {
            "name": "short_code",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "e.g. What city?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 2,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        }
    ],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "Why is {instance_id} shut down",
        "Why is {short_code} shut down",
        "what's the reason for {instance_id} shutdown",
        "what's the reason for {short_code} shutdown",
        "why is {instance_id} off",
        "why is {short_code} off"
    ],
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1498612810.201,
    "createdDate": 1496798177.871,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "edbadfd6-e1e5-47c5-9cf7-22c06acde602"
}


{
    "name": "Discovery",
    "slots": [],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "What can I ask you",
        "What can you do",
        "What functions do you have",
        "Tell me your available functions"
    ],
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1499530232.691,
    "createdDate": 1499530127.365,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "a4564397-238e-4c90-a4e4-c72e991c84c2"
}


{
    "name": "StartInstance",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "instance_id",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "instance_id",
            "slotTypeVersion": "2",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which instance?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 1,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        },
        {
            "name": "short_code",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which number?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 2,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        }
    ],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "Start instance {instance_id}",
        "Start instance {short_code}",
        "start {instance_id}",
        "start {short_code}",
        "turn on {instance_id}",
        "turn on {short_code}",
        "Spin up {instance_id}",
        "Spin up {short_code}"
    ],
    "confirmationPrompt": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": "Are you sure you want to start this instance?"
            }
        ],
        "maxAttempts": 3
    },
    "rejectionStatement": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": "OK, I won't start this instance."
            }
        ]
    },
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1498612493.964,
    "createdDate": 1497201911.538,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "3d24d22f-cf77-4d59-b773-14a2f3eda596"
}


{
    "name": "GetLaunchTime",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "instance_id",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "instance_id",
            "slotTypeVersion": "2",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which instance?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 1,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        },
        {
            "name": "short_code",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which instance?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 2,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        }
    ],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "When was {instance_id} started",
        "When was {short_code} started",
        "Uptime {instance_id}",
        "Uptime {short_code}",
        "Tell me when {instance_id} was launched",
        "Tell me when {short_code} was launched"
    ],
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1503272964.782,
    "createdDate": 1503272771.838,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "06328fa0-15b9-4875-a2e0-1b5f9ac1b940"
}


{
    "name": "StopInstance",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "instance_id",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "instance_id",
            "slotTypeVersion": "2",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which instance?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 1,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        },
        {
            "name": "short_code",
            "slotConstraint": "Optional",
            "slotType": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
            "valueElicitationPrompt": {
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Which number?"
                    }
                ],
                "maxAttempts": 2
            },
            "priority": 2,
            "sampleUtterances": []
        }
    ],
    "sampleUtterances": [
        "Stop instance {instance_id}",
        "Stop instance {short_code}",
        "Stop {instance_id}",
        "stop {short_code}",
        "shut down {instance_id}",
        "shut down {short_code}"
    ],
    "confirmationPrompt": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": "Are you sure you want to stop this instance?"
            }
        ],
        "maxAttempts": 3
    },
    "rejectionStatement": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": "OK, I won't stop this instance."
            }
        ]
    },
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
        "type": "CodeHook",
        "codeHook": {
            "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:get-ec2-status",
            "messageVersion": "1.0"
        }
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": 1498612645.996,
    "createdDate": 1497202428.572,
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "checksum": "faa549de-c578-4448-8010-0b46f2757722"
}
```

Expected is Bot should be created with the above code mentioned slots, utterances etc...

But it says error..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your intent codes are outside the Intent array. Ideally, if you exported a full bot from the Lex Console, it should look like this:

```
// Just the portion that includes the intents array
"intents": [
  {
    "name": "IntentName",
    "version": "1",
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
      "type": "ReturnIntent"
    },
    "sampleUtterances": [
      "Utterance 1",
      "Utterance 2",
      "Utterance 3"
    ],
    "slots": [
      {
        "sampleUtterances": [],
        "slotType": "Slot Name",
        "slotTypeVersion": "1",
        "slotConstraint": "Optional",
        "valueElicitationPrompt": {
          "messages": [
            {
              "contentType": "PlainText",
              "content": "Slot Prompt"
            }
          ],
          "maxAttempts": 2
        },
        "priority": 1,
        "name": "Slot Name (provided by developer)"
      }
    ],
    "conclusionStatement": {
      "messages": [ ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Intent 2",
    "version": "3",
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
      "type": "ReturnIntent"
    },
    "sampleUtterances": [
      "Utterance 1",
      "Utterance 2",
      "Utterance 3"
    ],
    "slots": [],
    "conclusionStatement": {
      "messages": [ ]
    }
  },

// repeat for all other intents
```

Unlike your case where only the intent name seems to be in the intents array. If you put your entered JSON into a JSON formatter website (I personally use https://jsonformatter.org/), it will show you which line the JSON error is detected.

Comment: I tried with several scripts and the same error.. Any advice plz.

Comment: @itechworkerz Can you share what the script you're trying looks like? That way I can help to debug your JSON.

Comment: I have shared the code in my Original post.. (In the Question). Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The intent json structure (to be imported) should be like the following as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/import-export-format.html#import-export-slot-type) (note the metadata and resource elements):

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "schemaVersion": "1.0",
    "importType": "LEX",
    "importFormat": "JSON"
  },
  "resource": {
    "description": "intent description",
    "rejectionStatement": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload",
          "content": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "intent name",
    "version": "version number",
    "fulfillmentActivity": {
      "type": "ReturnIntent or CodeHook"
    },
    "sampleUtterances": [
      "string",
      "string"
    ],
    "slots": [
      {
        "name": "slot name",
        "description": "slot description",
        "slotConstraint": "Required or Optional",
        "slotType": "slot type",
        "valueElicitationPrompt": {
          "messages": [
            {
              "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload",
              "content": "string"
            }
          ],
          "maxAttempts": value
        },
        "priority": value,
        "sampleUtterances": []
      }
    ],
    "confirmationPrompt": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload",
          "content": "string"
        },
        {
          "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload",
          "content": "string"
        }
      ],
      "maxAttempts": value
    },
    "slotTypes": [
        List of slot type JSON structures.
        For more information, see Slot Type structure.
    ]
  }
}
```